# How do i add another button in JButton

Tags: java, swing, button

I have 1 button i. but i need another. i added another JFrame and made a new class making the button. whenever i do

```java
frame.add(new TestButton());
```

it never works. i already have

```java
frame.add(new TestPanel());
```

which works. but its the only working one.
here is my TestButton code

```java
package App.Gui.Buttons;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import App.Gui.Event.ExitEvent;

public class TestButton extends JPanel {
    public TestButton() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ExitEvent.exit();
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
        add(button, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Books app"));
        add(contentPane, gbc);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1200, 750);
    }

    public static void addButton() {
        new TestButton();
        
    }
    
}
```

i need to add another button to do more stuff like you would need in a software. but it either never starts or, it bugs the buttons.
pls help.

Comment: Swing components don't support alpha based colors - `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` isn't going to work the way you want

Comment: It is often a better approach to add the button as the GUI is created, but disable it until it is appropriate to use. I would use an `Action` to establish the button, as it can be enabled / disabled and every control that uses it would be updated automatically.

Comment: `TestButton` is a container, not a window.  You need to add `TestButton` to a window (or other presented container)

Answer (score 1):

A `JPanel` can't be shown in of itself.  It needs to be added to a container hierarchy which is backed by a window based class, like `JFrame`.

This is a pretty basic concept, which suggests that you might be better off spending some time going through [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), especially [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestButton());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Also, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so you'll only be able to present a single component at each of it's five available positions.

So, if instead, you used a `GridLayout`, you could get multiple instances of `TestButton` on the window at the same time, for example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                frame.add(new TestButton());
                frame.add(new TestButton());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, Swing components also don't support alpha based colors, they are either opaque or they are not (no translucency - you can fake it, but that's beyond the scope)

So, I'd modify you code to look more like...

```
JButton button = new JButton();
//button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
//button.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setOpaque(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Also, good luck on been able to click that button by the way

### Full code...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestButton extends JPanel {

    public TestButton() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton();
        //        button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        //        button.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //ExitEvent.exit();
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
        add(button, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Books app"));
        add(contentPane, gbc);
    } 

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1200, 750);
    }

}
```

There are also issues with updating a realised window (adding/removing components once the window is visible on the screen).  Swing is lazy and you are required to request a layout and paint pass on the container you've modified (`invalidate` and `repaint`).

But you might find [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) more suitable to your needs instead - but since we don't have a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to know

Comment: it did not work, it just did this

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/938441736231981106/944348748958548028/unknown.png?width=921&height=663

Comment: grind layout did that. cardlayout removed both buttons completely

Comment: Stop - read the tutorials, take the time to experiment, SO isn't the place to get "tutorial" style informaiton